# i am trying to add multiple maps in a llist?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add maps in a list.

```
 map.addAll(
  {
    "sr_no": sr_no.text,
    'f_name': first_name.text,
    "l_name": last_name.text,
    "occupation": occupation.text,
    "mobile_no": mobile_no.text
  },
);
print(map);
list.add(map);
print(list);
```

I am have text field for data and button for onpressed event, but it updates the latest data to every map.

> OUTPUT ::

```
[{sr_no: 1, f_name: veer, l_name: Sharma, occupation: studing, mobile_no: 98656321471}, 
{sr_no: 1, f_name: veer, l_name: Sharma, occupation: studing, mobile_no: 98656321471}, 
{sr_no: 1, f_name: veer, l_name: Sharma, occupation: studing, mobile_no: 98656321471}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `map.addAll` you are changing the map and updating it with new values. This means it also changes every other map that are already in the list because they are literally the same map. What you maybe want to do instead is

```
 map = {
    "sr_no": sr_no.text,
    'f_name': first_name.text,
    "l_name": last_name.text,
    "occupation": occupation.text,
    "mobile_no": mobile_no.text
  };
```

To create new maps. Or even directly

```
list.add({
    "sr_no": sr_no.text,
    'f_name': first_name.text,
    "l_name": last_name.text,
    "occupation": occupation.text,
    "mobile_no": mobile_no.text
  });
```